# I downloaded Unreal Enging and it is 20 gb something. My computer has 1000 gb. Will the computer slow down significantly?

Tags: memory

As of now, my pc is 765 data. If I download Unreal Engine, will this cause major slowing when I browse the internet? Should I delete other stuff or will I be fine. I don't want my computer to explode or die.

Comment: Is this some kind of a meme

Comment: This is not a meme. I actually want to know before something happens

Comment: Have a search for "how much free space to leave on ssd" and see if the advice given is relevant to you. The computer won't explode or die. You might want to search for how to free up drive space - you didn't mention which OS the computer uses.